# $\limsup P[X_n\leq x]\leq P[X\leq x]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

> Let, $X_n$ converges $X$ in distribution. Give a counterexample of this statement: $\limsup P[X_n\leq x]\leq P[X\leq x]$

I know $\limsup P[X_n\leq x]\leq P[\limsup X\leq x]$. Then if I can give an example so that $X_n$ converges $X$ in distribution but $\limsup X_n\neq X$, it is done. But could not find one. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no counter example to the above statement because of the Portmanteau theorem. Specifically, the Portmanteau theorem says that weak convergence of probability measures $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ is equivalent to the statement that $\text{limsup}~\mu_n(F)\leq\mu(F)$ for all closed sets $F$. In your question the set $(-\infty,x]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, there is no counterexample.

Comment: thanks!${}{}{}$